# tabular environment: Showing overflow in binary addition?

Tags: tables

I have the following code to show binary addition of two numbers:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
      & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    + & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to indicate the overflow to the reader somehow. 2 ideas that
I have in mind are presented below:

### 1. Underbraces

[image]

### 2. Boxing the overflown bit

[image]

**EDIT**: User Ivan pointed out that using `fbox{1}` would do it and it works
perfectly. But I would still like to know how to put underbraces. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `\fbox{1}` ?

Comment: Actually, I had always used `fbox` on figures so it never occured to me. Thanks! I would still like to know the underbrace solution, so I am editing the question.

Comment: Check out this answer [Underbrace under table, stretching over multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78244)

Answer (score 2):

After checking out the post linked in the comments I have decided
on the following solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cllll}
            & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        $+$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \hline
       \fbox{1} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \hline \\[-3ex]
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\upbracefill} \\
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\small significant bits}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces basically what I want:
[image]

If the box is a little too close to the `hrule` s then you can
increase the row separation using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}` and adjust the `\\[]` lengths accordingly!